# Extract number of working days from date in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Is there any way to extract the number of working days / business days (in UK) using a Date variable in R? Example:

| Date | Working days |
| --- | --- |
| Mar-21 | 23 |
| Apr-21 | 20 |

Answer (score 0):

```r
workingdays <- function(date,
                        wdays = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"),
                        holidays = as.Date(c())) {
  day1 <- as.POSIXlt(date)
  day1$mday <- 1
  dayn <- day1
  dayn$mon <- dayn$mon + 1
  dayn$mday <- dayn$mday - 1
  day1 <- as.Date(day1)
  dayn <- as.Date(dayn)
  mapply(function(fm, to) {
    alldays <- seq(fm, to, by = "day")
    alldays <- alldays[!alldays %in% holidays]
    sum(weekdays(alldays) %in% wdays)
  }, day1, dayn)
}

workingdays(as.Date(paste("01", x$Date), format="%d %b-%y"))
# [1] 23 22

workingdays(as.Date(paste("01", x$Date), format="%d %b-%y"), 
            holidays = as.Date("2021-04-05"))
# [1] 23 21
```

Choose whichever days you prefer to working/business days.

So somehow you will need to find a list of holidays to include in the `holidays=` argument.

Comment: Tried to create a new variable using the line of code given but got an error.

clean_file <- raw_file %>% 
  mutate(Days_Count = weekdays(do.call(seq.Date, c(as.list(as.Date(paste("2021", raw_file$Date), format = "%Y %b-%d")), by = "day")))))

Comment: I think I misunderstood ... you want to determine the number of workdays from each of those dates to *today*?

Comment: So for every month in 2021 i'd like the number of working days on the next column if thats possible?

Comment: Your date column is ambiguous, you need to be explicit. Is that `Mar-21` as in `March of the year 2021`? Y2K was a problem for a really good reason.

Comment: Yes March 2021. In R it appears as "2021-03-01" so maybe this was the problem? Is there a way around this out having to use a start date and an end date?

Comment: The first problem is mine, I misinterpreted what process you needed. The second is because `"Mar-21"` is ambiguous and you didn't specify. Standby, working it.

Comment: Is `Date` originally a *real R `Date`*, or is it always this abbreviated string?

Comment: Either way, the function can accept either format, `"%b-%y"` or a proper `Date` object.

Comment: In UK there are 20 working days in April due to Easter Holidays (2 bank holidays)

Comment: Do you think that's important to include in the question? Is there a list somewhere of all holidays?